# Remove closest empty siblings

Tags: jquery, string, siblings, closest

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<p></p>
<p>not empty</p>
<p>not empty</p>
<p></p>
<div class="wrapper">
    // more content inside
</div>
<p>  </p> <-- whitespace, also removed
<p></p>
<p>not empty</p>
```

How do I remove the empty `<p>` tags closest to `.wrapper`? I want a result like this:

```
<p></p>
<p>not empty</p>
<p>not empty</p>
<div class="wrapper">
    // more content inside
</div>
<p>not empty</p>
```

So I don't want to remove all empty siblings, just the empty ones next to `.wrapper`, even if there are multiple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.prevUntil`/`.nextUntil` combined with the `:not(:empty)` selector:  http://jsfiddle.net/vEtv8/5/.

```
$("div.wrapper")
    .​​​​​​​​​​nextUntil(":not(p), :not(:empty)").remove().end()
    .prevUntil(":not(p), :not(:empty)").remove();
```

`:empty` doesn't count whitespace elements as being empty, though. You could use a function for that: http://jsfiddle.net/vEtv8/4/.

```
var stopPredicate = function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return !$this.is("p") || $.trim($this.text()) !== "";
};

$("div.wrapper")
    .nextUntil(stopPredicate).remove().end()
    .prevUntil(stopPredicate).remove();
```

Comment: Almost, but it doesn't remove if it contains whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/pptRP/

Comment: Actually, not quite done yet. This removes all empty sibling tags. I only want to remove <p> tags.

Comment: @qwerty: Oops, you're right. You could add an extra check like http://jsfiddle.net/vEtv8/4/.

Comment: +1 in part because this demonstrates that the documentation for `.nextUntil()`/`.prevUntil()` is wrong -- it doesn't mention that you can use a function as the selector!

Comment: @Jon: Funny, indeed it does not state that. In fact, `.parentsUntil` also works with a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.wrapper').prevAll('p:empty').nextAll('p:empty').remove();
```